# Renaming an unnamed variable with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

I have to read a bunch of `.xlsx` files into R, which I do with `readxl::read_excel()`. Each of these files does not give a variable name for the first column. Since there are plenty of files, I do not want to change those manually.

In order to process the data properly, it is necessary to give these first columns a name. In the end, I want to write a function that I can call for each of these `.xlsx` files (e.g. using `purrr:map`) and within this function I would prefer to get a single pipe as a solution.

Unfortunately, ``` dplyr::rename(df, timeseries = ``) ``` throws the following error:

> Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name

Using the column index (`dplyr::rename(df, timeseries = 1)`) does not work either:

> Error: Arguments to `rename()` must be unquoted variable names.
>       Argument `timeseries` is not.

How can I avoid to interrupt the pipe in order to rename the variable by `names(df)[1] <- "timeseries"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished with `dplyr::select()` in the following way:

```
select(df, timeseries = 1, everything())
```

Obviously, `dplyr::select()` can handle column indices, which allows this solution.

Please comment if you are aware of any particular reason why this is not possible with `dplyr:rename()`!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `rename` and a column index (in this case 1), you can do

```
rename_(df, timeseries = names(df)[1])
```

When chaining, use a dot:

```
df %>% ... %>% rename_(timeseries = names(.)[1])
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this alternative approach although it feels to be little harder to read due to `(.)[1]`.

Comment: No probs, just wanted to highlight how to do it with `rename`. `select` has the side-effect that it re-arranges the columns in your data frame, so if an issue, you could just write a wrapper function around `rename` to avoid the `(.)` syntax

Comment: Good point. Rearranging is not an issue here, but in general it might be. +1